# Android intent service in native code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Is  it possible to create an android intent service in C? If so how?

I need an intent service that is launched from an activity, and runs on demand so it wont be constantly running when the activity is paused.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot write an Android service without touching Java.

Actually, you cannot even write an Android activity in pure C. The [native activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) is but another Java class that defines a lot of native methods that you must implement in C. Anyone can write a similar Java class for their app, and use it instead of the one supplied by system. Furthermore, there are some situations when you must extend this class (using Java) to achieve your goals (e.g. if you must use a prebuilt third-party shared library on devices before Lollipop).

For Service, Android does not provide a standard wrapper similar to Native Activity, but you can learn the [NativeActivity source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/NativeActivity.java) and build a similar generic Java wrapper for a NativeService, with lots of native methods that will implement all app-specific logic.